# How to make a table with multiple headers responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-table

Could someone explain me how to make this table responsive?
It has two headers on the top and on the left side. I know how to make a table responsive with only a header on the top, but not with both of it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>not titled</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th scope="col" style="background-color:red;">Title</th>
        <th scope="col" style="background-color:red;">Title</th>
        <th scope="col" style="background-color:red;">Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:red;">Title</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:red;">Title</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:red;">Title</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see this link http://dbushell.com/2012/01/05/responsive-tables-2/

Comment: thank you. That is a way with a scrollbar. But is there also a way to make it responsive with ::before and the content-property?